# SQL instead-of trigger

Tags: sql, sqlite, triggers, view

I have these tables:

- Movie ( mID, title, year, director )
- Reviewer ( rID, name )
- Rating ( rID, mID, stars, ratingDate )

and some views:

- View `LateRating` contains movie ratings after January 20, 2011. The view contains the movie ID, movie title, number of stars, and rating date.

  ```
  create view LateRating as 
    select distinct R.mID, title, stars, ratingDate 
    from Rating R, Movie M 
    where R.mID = M.mID 
    and ratingDate > '2011-01-20'
  ```
- View `HighlyRated` contains movies with at least one rating above 3 stars. The view contains the movie ID and movie title.

  ```
  create view HighlyRated as 
    select mID, title 
    from Movie 
    where mID in (select mID from Rating where stars > 3)
  ```
- View `NoRating` contains movies with no ratings in the database. The view contains the movie ID and movie title.

  ```
  create view NoRating as 
    select mID, title 
    from Movie 
    where mID not in (select mID from Rating)
  ```

Here's my data set : http://dfiles.eu/files/vlylwacdd

I'm asked to write an instead-of trigger that enables updates to the title attribute of view LateRating.How can I do that? I'm not used to triggers and views too much :(

Comment: Did you post this question from the stanford databases class? if so, honor code,yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
CREATE trigger update_LateRating_title INSTEAD OF UPDATE OF title ON LateRating
BEGIN
  UPDATE Movie SET title = new.title WHERE movie.mID = old.mID;
END;
```

As requested in the comment, here is a trigger to update only movies that have reviews greater than 2 in LateRating:

```
CREATE trigger update_LateRating_title INSTEAD OF 
UPDATE OF title ON LateRating
BEGIN
  UPDATE Movie SET title = new.title 
  WHERE movie.mID = old.mID 
  AND movie.mID IN (SELECT mID FROM LateRating WHERE stars > 2);
END;
```

(There are different ways to interpret this later request. Should title updates be allowed for the *movie* which has more than 2 stars somewhere or only for the *record* actually having more than 2 stars? My code is for the former choice).

Comment: Really thanks but there is just one hitch.How can I let it update only movies that have reviews greater than 2 in LateRating.

Comment: Anton do you have MSN account or something that I can contact you?I have couple of similar questions.